# What type of hard disks do netbooks use?

Tags: hard-drive, netbook

Is there any information on the standard hard disks that [netbooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netbook) use, are they just standard SATA notebook drives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most are using the SATA Hard Disks (2.5")...  You can still find some with SSDs, but it seems as though manufacturers have shifted back to the SATA drives in favor of more storage space.

I recently purchased the Toshiba NB205 and am in the process of upgrading the RAM to 2 GB and putting Windows 7 Ultimate on there.  I thought about adding a SSD, but I should do that in my primary machine's first...

So to sum this all up...  2.5" SATA Hard Disks seems to be the current standard, but you need to check the specs on the specific models...

Comment: do you really believe storage is the reason? i think not. with a SSD you don't have to treat the bloody thing like a raw egg, as it happens with platter hard drives, every bump could be the end of it. speed and robustness is what i prefer, storage is easily expandable. a 32 GB SDHC card or two will go a long way.

Comment: I saw your comment relative to other devices, tend to agree.  But they went from 4 and 8 gb drives to 160 and 250...  I can only assume that they were getting some backlash for folks saying, but I can't put any movies on there...

Comment: personally i never had a problem with the 4GB disk space on the 701's SSD. some folks have even managed to install windows 7 on it. what's the big deal? if you rip your DVDs to MKV, you easily get 100 movies onto a 32 GB SDHC, right? :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends, currently most laptops have 2.5" SATA HDDs only.

You can have a look at *[Hard disk drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)* (Wikipedia) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Most netbooks today use standard [2.5" SATA HDDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Form_factors).

Comment: anf if you're asking me, they abandoned SSDs because a silly eee pc 701 with a celery CPU was booting XP in less than 20 secands and starting programs in split seconds ... now this makes other laptops look really really bad! :)

Comment: So it wasn't anything to do with relative cost per mb then? SSDs presently cost a lot more than a hard disk with the same(ish) capacity :)

Comment: you cannot compare the cost per MB. you cannot sell a $200 netbook with a 128 MB SSD, but a 16 GB SSD is actually cheaper than 160 GB platter HDD, the SSD is much faster and you can toss the netbook around without breaking the storage device (not that i advocate reckless handling). as i commented elsewhere, storage is easily expandable with SDHC cards.

Comment: @molly while you're right, the non-super-user doesn't see that; all they see is "160G here, 16G there?" and all they think is "gimme more!"

Comment: ain't that the sad truth? :)

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed quite a lot in the decade or so since the question was posted, but there's still a significant number of netbook class systems.

*Typically*, netbooks of that era used 7mm or 5mm z height 2.5mm laptop drives. Z height refers to the thickness of the drives. It's also possible that early ones might use IDE. If its between M.2 and IDE, its plausible you would see "traditional" Sata drives or M.2. Something like a inspiron mini 10 (from a decade ago) for example would probably come with a sata HDD upgradable to a sata SSD.

More recently, the low end would use emmc storage, either soldered in or socketed, and higher end units would use flash storage, either through a sata or NVMe interface.